# Ctypes - How to parser buffer content?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a code use `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW` to enumerate USB vendor id and product id , I read from buffer as `<ctypes.LP_c_wchar object at 0x000001A3361F4C40>`,how can i parse ?

Buffer

```
result = ct.cast(PropertyBuffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))
```

code

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w
import uuid

SetupAPI = ct.WinDLL('SetupAPI')

ULONG_PTR = w.WPARAM

class HDEVINFO(w.HANDLE):
    pass

class GUID(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Data1', ct.c_ulong),
                ('Data2', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data3', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data4', ct.c_ubyte * 8))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"GUID('{self}')"

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{{{self.Data1:08x}-{self.Data2:04x}-{self.Data3:04x}-'
                f'{bytes(self.Data4[:2]).hex()}-{bytes(self.Data4[2:]).hex()}}}')

    def __init__(self,guid=None):
        if guid is not None:
            data = uuid.UUID(guid)
            self.Data1 = data.time_low
            self.Data2 = data.time_mid
            self.Data3 = data.time_hi_version
            self.Data4[0] = data.clock_seq_hi_variant
            self.Data4[1] = data.clock_seq_low
            self.Data4[2:] = data.node.to_bytes(6,'big')

PGUID = ct.POINTER(GUID)

GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = GUID('{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}')

class SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('cbSize', w.DWORD), 
                ('ClassGuid', GUID), 
                ('DevInst', w.DWORD), 
                ('Reserved', ULONG_PTR))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={self.ClassGuid}, DevInst={self.DevInst})'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cbSize = ct.sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)      

PSP_DEVINFO_DATA = ct.POINTER(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes = PGUID, w.PWCHAR, w.HWND, w.DWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype = HDEVINFO

SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.argtypes = HDEVINFO, w.DWORD, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA
SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.restype = w.BOOL 

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA.argtypes = HDEVINFO, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA, 
w.DWORD, w.PDWORD, w.PBYTE, w.DWORD, w.PDWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA.restype = w.BOOL

SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.argtypes = HDEVINFO,
SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.restype = w.BOOL

DIGCF_DEFAULT         =  0x00000001  
DIGCF_PRESENT         =  0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES      =  0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE         =  0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE =  0x00000010

ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
Enumerator = None
hwndParent = None
Flags = DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT

devinfo = SP_DEVINFO_DATA()

hDevInfo = SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(ClassGuid, Enumerator, hwndParent, Flags)


DeviceInfoSet = hDevInfo
DeviceInfoData = ct.byref(devinfo)    
SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001
PropertyRegDataType = None
PropertyBufferSize = 0
RequiredSize = w.DWORD()

try:
    MemberIndex = 0
    while SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, MemberIndex, ct.byref(devinfo)):       
        print(devinfo)          
        SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
                                               hDevInfo,
                                               ct.byref(devinfo),
                                               SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
                                               PropertyRegDataType,
                                               None, 
                                               PropertyBufferSize ,
                                               ct.byref(RequiredSize))
    
        PropertyBuffer = (w.BYTE * RequiredSize.value)()
        if not SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
                                                     hDevInfo,
                                                     ct.byref(devinfo),
                                                     SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
                                                     PropertyRegDataType,
                                                     PropertyBuffer, 
                                                     ct.sizeof(PropertyBuffer),
                                                     None):
           break
        result = ct.cast(PropertyBuffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))
        print(result)
        MemberIndex += 1            
           
finally:
    SetupAPI.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing:

- [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
- [[MS.Docs]: SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW function (setupapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertyw) for info on how to parse the results. For example, according to [[MS.Docs]: Registry Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types) (**emphasis** is mine):

  > **REG_MULTI_SZ** - **A sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string** (\0). The following is an example: *String1\0String2\0String3\0LastString\0\0* The first \0 terminates the first string, the second to the last \0 terminates the last string, and the final \0 terminates the sequence. Note that the final terminator must be factored into the length of the string.

Your code had several flaws (out of which matter most):

- Continuation on a separate line of `SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA.argtypes` (without a ***\***) - your program only works because the following bullet is masking this
- Definig them for *SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty**A*** but using *SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty**W*** - which yields ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011) for more details
- Converting the array to a pointer doesn't make any sense, as it loses size information

I modified your script to a working version:

- Extended *parse_data* to accommodate new data types (*REG_DWORD*, *REG_SZ*, *REG_MULTI_SZ*) - as originally **only *REG_MULTI_SZ* data** (corresponding to *SPDRP_HARDWAREID* property) **was** mentioned / **required**
- Improved error handling
- Extended functionality
- Other minor things

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys
import uuid
import winreg as wr

from ctypes import wintypes as wt


ULONG_PTR = wt.WPARAM
HDEVINFO = wt.HANDLE


class GUID(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("Data1", ct.c_ulong),
        ("Data2", ct.c_ushort),
        ("Data3", ct.c_ushort),
        ("Data4", ct.c_ubyte * 8),
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"GUID('{self}')"

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{{{self.Data1:08x}-{self.Data2:04x}-{self.Data3:04x}-"
                f"{bytes(self.Data4[:2]).hex()}-{bytes(self.Data4[2:]).hex()}}}")

    def __init__(self,guid=None):
        if guid is not None:
            data = uuid.UUID(guid)
            self.Data1 = data.time_low
            self.Data2 = data.time_mid
            self.Data3 = data.time_hi_version
            self.Data4[0] = data.clock_seq_hi_variant
            self.Data4[1] = data.clock_seq_low
            self.Data4[2:] = data.node.to_bytes(6, "big")

PGUID = ct.POINTER(GUID)


class SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("cbSize", wt.DWORD),
        ("ClassGuid", GUID),
        ("DevInst", wt.DWORD),
        ("Reserved", ULONG_PTR),
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={self.ClassGuid}, DevInst={self.DevInst})"

    def __init__(self):
        self.cbSize = ct.sizeof(self.__class__)


PSP_DEVINFO_DATA = ct.POINTER(SP_DEVINFO_DATA)

GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = GUID("{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}")


kernel32 = ct.WinDLL("Kernel32")

GetLastError = kernel32.GetLastError
GetLastError.argtypes = ()
GetLastError.restype = wt.DWORD

setupapi = ct.WinDLL("Setupapi")

#is_wide = True  # Determine whether using WIDE or ANSI functions

SetupDiGetClassDevs = setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsW #if is_wide else setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsA
SetupDiGetClassDevs.argtypes = (PGUID, wt.PWCHAR, wt.HWND, wt.DWORD)
SetupDiGetClassDevs.restype = HDEVINFO

SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo = setupapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo
SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.argtypes = (HDEVINFO, wt.DWORD, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA)
SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.restype = wt.BOOL

SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty = setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW #if is_wide else setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.argtypes = (HDEVINFO, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA, wt.DWORD, wt.PDWORD, wt.PBYTE, wt.DWORD, wt.PDWORD)
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.restype = wt.BOOL

SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList = setupapi.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.argtypes = (HDEVINFO,)
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList.restype = wt.BOOL


DIGCF_DEFAULT = 0x00000001
DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE = 0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000010


def parse_data(arr, reg_data_type):
    if reg_data_type is wr.REG_DWORD:
        return wt.DWORD.from_buffer(arr).value
    elif reg_data_type in (wr.REG_SZ, wr.REG_MULTI_SZ):
        WArrType = wt.WCHAR * (arr._length_ // ct.sizeof(wt.WCHAR))  # Convert from char array to wchar_t array (halving size)
        warr = WArrType.from_buffer(arr)   # @TODO - cfati: You should probably use MultiByteToWideChar or mbstowcs here.
        ret = str(warr[:len(warr)]).rstrip("\x00")
        if reg_data_type is wr.REG_MULTI_SZ:
            return ret.split("\x00")
        elif reg_data_type is wr.REG_SZ:
            return ret
    else:  # More types could be handled here
        return arr


def main(*argv):
    ClassGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
    Enumerator = None
    hwndParent = None
    Flags = DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT

    dev_info = SP_DEVINFO_DATA()

    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ClassGuid, Enumerator, hwndParent, Flags)


    DeviceInfoSet = hDevInfo
    property_reg_data_type = wt.DWORD(0)
    required_size = wt.DWORD(0)

    SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 0x00000001
    SPDRP_CLASS = 0x00000007
    SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME = 0x0000000C
    SPDRP_CAPABILITIES = 0x0000000F
    SPDRP_BUSNUMBER = 0x00000015
    SPDRP_DEVTYPE = 0x00000019
    SPDRP_EXCLUSIVE = 0x0000001A
    SPDRP_CHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000001B
    SPDRP_ADDRESS = 0x0000001C
    SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE = 0x00000022
    props = (SPDRP_HARDWAREID, SPDRP_CLASS, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, SPDRP_CAPABILITIES)

    ERROR_INVALID_DATA = 0x0D
    ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A

    try:
        MemberIndex = 0
        while SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, MemberIndex, ct.byref(dev_info)):
            print(dev_info)
            keep_running = True
            for prop in props:
                print(f"  Prop: {prop}")
                if not SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                        hDevInfo, ct.byref(dev_info), prop,
                        None, None, 0, ct.byref(required_size)):
                    gle = GetLastError()
                    if gle == ERROR_INVALID_DATA:
                        print("    Unsupported")
                        continue
                    elif gle != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                        print("    Fail0:", gle)
                        keep_running = False
                        break

                #print("  kkt", prop, required_size.value)
                PropertyBuffer = wt.BYTE * required_size.value
                property_buffer = PropertyBuffer()
                if not SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                        hDevInfo, ct.byref(dev_info), prop,
                        ct.byref(property_reg_data_type),
                        property_buffer, ct.sizeof(PropertyBuffer), None):
                    gle = GetLastError()
                    print("    Fail1:", gle)
                    if gle != ERROR_INVALID_DATA:
                        keep_running = False
                        break
                print(f"    Data type: {property_reg_data_type.value} \
                        \n    Buf: {property_buffer} \
                        \n    Data: {parse_data(property_buffer, property_reg_data_type.value)}")
            if not keep_running:
                break
            MemberIndex += 1

    finally:
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q072847468]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}, DevInst=1)
>   Prop: 1
>     Data type: 7
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_108 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: ['USB\\VID_0BDA&PID_8153&REV_3100', 'USB\\VID_0BDA&PID_8153']
>   Prop: 7
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_8 object at 0x000002287ECF60C0>
>     Data: Net
>   Prop: 12
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_74 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #2
>   Prop: 15
>     Data type: 4
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_4 object at 0x000002287ECF6040>
>     Data: 148
> SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}, DevInst=2)
>   Prop: 1
>     Data type: 7
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_108 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: ['USB\\VID_045E&PID_00CB&REV_0100', 'USB\\VID_045E&PID_00CB']
>   Prop: 7
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_18 object at 0x000002287ECF8040>
>     Data: HIDClass
>   Prop: 12
>     Unsupported
>   Prop: 15
>     Data type: 4
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_4 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: 132
> SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}, DevInst=3)
>   Prop: 1
>     Data type: 7
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_108 object at 0x000002287ECF80C0>
>     Data: ['USB\\VID_045E&PID_07F8&REV_0300', 'USB\\VID_045E&PID_07F8']
>   Prop: 7
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_8 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: USB
>   Prop: 12
>     Unsupported
>   Prop: 15
>     Data type: 4
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_4 object at 0x000002287ECF8040>
>     Data: 132
> SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}, DevInst=4)
>   Prop: 1
>     Data type: 7
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_108 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: ['USB\\VID_8087&PID_0A2B&REV_0001', 'USB\\VID_8087&PID_0A2B']
>   Prop: 7
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_20 object at 0x000002287ECF80C0>
>     Data: Bluetooth
>   Prop: 12
>     Unsupported
>   Prop: 15
>     Data type: 4
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_4 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: 128
> SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}, DevInst=5)
>   Prop: 1
>     Data type: 7
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_108 object at 0x000002287ECF8040>
>     Data: ['USB\\VID_0C45&PID_6713&REV_5605', 'USB\\VID_0C45&PID_6713']
>   Prop: 7
>     Data type: 1
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_8 object at 0x000002287E6F4F40>
>     Data: USB
>   Prop: 12
>     Unsupported
>   Prop: 15
>     Data type: 4
>     Buf: <__main__.c_byte_Array_4 object at 0x000002287ECF80C0>
>     Data: 128
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: If I use SPDRP_BUSNUMBER, how to modify the code,After I modified the code output is blank

Comment: @user19212551 See [Registry Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types).  `SPDRP_BUSNUMBER` is a `REG_DWORD` so is returned as  a 4-byte little-endian value, not a `REG_MULTI_SZ`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are initializing and calling the "W" version of the `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` API:

```
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW.argtypes = HDEVINFO, PSP_DEVINFO_DATA, w.DWORD, w.PDWORD, w.PBYTE, w.DWORD, w.PDWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW.restype = w.BOOL
```

The registry value being read is a `MULTI_SZ`, which is multiple zero-terminated strings, the last of which is double-terminated.  The following function casts the return buffer to a C `wchar_t*`, but then uses string slicing to extracts "length" characters starting at that pointer address.  The length is determined by dividing the returned buffer size by the size of a `WCHAR`.  Then the trailing nulls are stripped from the data and the individual strings are split by the other nulls:

```
def get_multi_sz(buffer, length):
    result = ct.cast(buffer, ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))
    strings = result[:RequiredSize.value // ct.sizeof(w.WCHAR)]
    return strings.rstrip('\x00').split('\x00')
```

Finally, in your `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` while loop, print the list of strings returned by each device:

```py
MemberIndex = 0
while SetupAPI.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, MemberIndex, ct.byref(devinfo)):
    print(devinfo)
    SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
            hDevInfo, ct.byref(devinfo), SPDRP_HARDWAREID, PropertyRegDataType,
            None, PropertyBufferSize, ct.byref(RequiredSize))

    PropertyBuffer = (w.BYTE * RequiredSize.value)()
    if not SetupAPI.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
            hDevInfo, ct.byref(devinfo), SPDRP_HARDWAREID, PropertyRegDataType,
            PropertyBuffer, ct.sizeof(PropertyBuffer), None):
        break

    print(get_multi_sz(PropertyBuffer, RequiredSize.value))
    MemberIndex += 1
```

Output with these changes (on my system, anyway):

```py
SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}, DevInst=1)
['USB\\VID_046D&PID_C52B&REV_1201', 'USB\\VID_046D&PID_C52B']
SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}, DevInst=2)
['USB\\VID_046D&PID_C01B&REV_1800', 'USB\\VID_046D&PID_C01B']
SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}, DevInst=3)
['USB\\VID_03F0&PID_0122&REV_0100', 'USB\\VID_03F0&PID_0122']
SP_DEVINFO_DATA(ClassGuid={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}, DevInst=4)
['USB\\VID_046D&PID_0A87&REV_0112', 'USB\\VID_046D&PID_0A87']
```

Using a tool like [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html), you can verify the Hardware ID strings match.  Here's an excerpt from that tool that matches the 3rd device's hardware IDs above:

```
      ======================== USB Device ========================

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Device Description       : USB Composite Device
Device Path              : \\?\USB#VID_03F0&PID_0122#5&35eda8e7&0&1#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
Kernel Name              : \Device\USBPDO-10
Device ID                : USB\VID_03F0&PID_0122\5&35EDA8E7&0&1
Hardware IDs             : USB\VID_03F0&PID_0122&REV_0100 USB\VID_03F0&PID_0122
```

Comment: I can also read back the message using `result = ct.cast(PropertyBuffer,ct.POINTER(w.WCHAR))[:52]`, but I tried it randomly, I don't know the reason

Comment: @user19212551 A `REG_MULTI_SZ` is returned as a pointer to a string.  In Python to read multiple characters from a string pointer, string slicing reads the memory and converts it to a Python string.  You need to use the correct buffer size returned by the function, but be aware it is a *byte*-size, so if using the "W" functions the characters are 16-bit and the returned size must be divided by 2.  The `get_multi_sz` function above does that.

Comment: @user19212551 Also note that different registry queries return different registry types.  `PropertyRegDataType` returns the registry type.  Instead of passing `None` pass a `w.DWORD()` instance by reference like was done for `RequiredSize` and it will return the type.  Each type is parsed differently.